# Where do I set the SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS?

Tags: .net, jvm, sonarqube

I am trying to use SonarQube to analyze a rather big project. I ran into an issue where it tells me I don't have enough memory so I set out to figure this out. I understand that I need to increase the amount of memory that Java can use, but I don't understand where it wants me to set the variable "SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS". It keeps telling me it's not set so it defaults to 1024. But that obviously wasn't enough.

So I ask, where do I set this variable? The variable appears to exist in the sonar-runner.bat file in my `...\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin` folder but changing it doesn't do anything as the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` deletes those files straight away to make them again, when I do the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end` command.

What do I do?

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace of the out of memory exception just to know at which phase the analysis is failing, as well as your SonarQube server version? This might help us reduce the memory usage

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam I will get back to you when I meet in at work tomorrow. It's 5.4 and it's an ASP project with heavy use of JavaScript and C#. I read in another post somewhere that with C/C++ projects, the runner could pick up on files that didn't belong there and could increase the size like crazy and thus run out of memory, but that shouldn't be the case for C# projects.

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam How do I get a log from `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe`? There are no logs from it's usage anywhere. http://puu.sh/ohGTQ/7953fd351a.png

Comment: It seems that you're setting the value of `SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS` too high for what's available on your machine / VM. `-Xms` is the minimum amount of memory that the Java VM should use from the moment it starts, and according to your screenshot - it's failing to start because it can't allocate all of it. Either reduce value of `-Xms` or increase the memory available to your VM / machine.

Comment: The machine got 16 gb of RAM and tells me that I can use 15 gb of it. It is 64-bit, so I don't quite understand how it can be deemed too high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set `SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS` as an environment variable ([documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner/#troubleshooting)).

Comment: It isn't even mentioned in the sonar source (I searched for it in branch-5.6). I think in current sonar (around from 5.x) it can be set in `sonar.properties`, there are various jvm opts.

Comment: Concur, this works, see https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Troubleshooting

Comment: the link in the answer is expired or not working for me